# Regexp to match string on TCL

Tags: regex, tcl, string-matching

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status           Protocol

GigabitEthernet0/0/0        unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Gi0/0/0.201                 10.10.10.30     YES NVRAM  up                    up    
GigabitEthernet0/1          unassigned      YES NVRAM  admin down           down    
GigabitEthernet0/1.201       unassigned     YES manual admin down           down    
GigabitEthernet0/2/0        1.2.3.4         YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2/0.203    10.10.10.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

This some output from a command on router. I want to be able to match a string that starts with `Gi` or `GigabitEthernet` and end in `.20(1-20)` like `.201` or `.202` or `.203` upto `.220`.

So it would match `GigabitEthernet0/1.201`  or `Gi0/0/0.201`.

Once there is a match , I want be able to put that complete string in a variable and use it somewhere else. If there are multiple matches I want them in multiple variables.

Please coders help me out. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Gi(?:gabitEthernet).*?\.2(?:0[1-9]|1\d|20).*`?

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/2XkA8k

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
set text {Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status           Protocol

GigabitEthernet0/0/0        unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
Gi0/0/0.201                 10.10.10.30     YES NVRAM  up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/1          unassigned      YES NVRAM  admin down           down
GigabitEthernet0/1.201       unassigned     YES manual admin down           down
GigabitEthernet0/2/0        1.2.3.4         YES NVRAM  up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/2/0.203    10.10.10.1      YES NVRAM  up                    up }

set interfaces [regexp -all -inline {\mGi\S+\.2(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)\M} $text]
puts $interfaces
```

```
Gi0/0/0.201 GigabitEthernet0/1.201 GigabitEthernet0/2/0.203
```

See https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm and https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm

Comment: I added the word boundaries `\m` `\M` so that you won't match something like "xxxGi0.2012345"

Comment: Thank you Glenn. That's really brilliant how you put it. Meanwhile I have been trying and came up with    (Gi.+)(\/[0-2])([./]?)([2][0-2][1-9]) . It gave me matches but I like the numbers being in just 1 substring. Thanks again